# Piping email to program with cPanel and Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, cpanel, piping

I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/piping-emails-laravel-application/) on how to pipe email with Laravel and Cpanel but I can't setup forwared in cPanel. I tried to use every option available :

```
public_html/artisan --env=local email-parse
/usr/bin/php -q /var/public_html/artisan --env=local email-parse
/usr/bin/php -q public_html/artisan --env=local email-parse
```

I don't know what else can be made here, so this is why I'm asking here on SO.

The error I get is

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
>
> pipe to |/home/xxxx/public_html/artisan --env=local email-parse
>       generated by todo@yyyyy.com 
>   local delivery failed
>
> The following text was generated during the delivery attempt:
>
> ------ pipe to |/home/xxxx/public_html/artisan --env=local email-parse
>          generated by todo@yyyyy.com ------
>
> Could not exec '/home/xxxx/public_html/artisan'

Comment: No. You get different errors depending on which command you use. What error do you get with the second command? (The first and last are wrong).

Comment: i recently had a similar problem with Postfix piping that produced the same error. It was solved by changing permissions ... in your case, you could try `chmod 755 /home/xxxx/public_html/artisan`

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing a similar problem, but in my case at least I got Artisan to work. It finds artisan but it doesn't find the command I created. The url I used was

```
/pathtoartisan/artisan emailparse
```

1. I removed the dash.
2. It seems you are referencing artisan on the public_html folder, which is not a good practice.

Comment: public_html can to be a not public  folder, if you modifiy your virtualhost (if you are root, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need for retrieving emails with a laravel application and using CPanel, fortunately Shweta posted this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041340/retrieving-emails-using-laravel-and-imap-failed-to-pass-variable-to-view) where show some code of how to read email from gmail and save it to a DB. I am using the code which it works from gmail and also using it with my CPanel credentials and works too.