# Retrieving Emails Using Laravel and IMAP,failed to pass variable to view

Tags: email, laravel-5, imap

I have written a code to display emails form gmail:

```
 public function getMail()
{
    /* connect to gmail */
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = 'xyz@gmail.com';
    $password = 'xyz';

    $inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());

    $emails = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');


    if ($emails) {
        $output = '';

        rsort($emails);

        foreach ($emails as $email_number) {
            $header = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $email_number);

            $from = $header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;
            $toaddress = $header->toaddress;
            echo '<strong>To:</strong> ' . $toaddress . '<br>';
            echo '<strong>From:</strong> ' . $from . '<br>';
            $message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.1));
            if ($message == '') {
                $message = (imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1));
                echo '<strong>Body:</strong> ' . $message . '<br>';
                echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
    imap_expunge($inbox);
    imap_close($inbox);
}
```

This works fine, but when i pass variables '$toaddress', '$from' to view it shows only first email id. And i have to add a view button,upon click of that there should come body of that respective email and goes to different method, i passed para **$message** to that method,

```
$this->showMail($message);
```

and method is:

```
    public function showMail($message){

    return view('emails.showmail',compact('message'));
}
```

but on click of button there is missing argument error. If anyone knows help me through this!

Comment: What is your issue exactly? Is it related to having only single email data passed to view, or how to display email body?

Comment: I have to display list of persons who send email, but on click of some button there should come respective body of that mail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some changes and it worked!

```
public function getMail()
{
    /* connect to gmail */
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = 'xyz@gmail.com';
    $password = 'xyz';

    $inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());

    $emails = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');

    if ($emails) {
        $output = '';
        $mails = array();

        rsort($emails);

        foreach ($emails as $email_number) {
            $header = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $email_number);
            $message = quoted_printable_decode (imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1));

            $from = $header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;
            $toaddress = $header->toaddress;
            if(imap_search($inbox, 'UNSEEN')){
                /*Store from and message body to database*/
                DB::table('email')->insert(['from'=>$from, 'body'=>$message]);
                return view('emails.display');
            }
            else{
                $data = Email::all();
                return view('emails.display',compact('data'));

            }
        }
    }
        imap_close($inbox);
}

public function showMail($id){

    // get the id
    $message = Email::findOrFail($id);
    $m = $message->body;
    // show the view and pass the nerd to it
    return view('emails.showmail',compact('m'));
}
```

I stored all my emails in my own database, and then displayed in display.blade.php.

**display.blade.php:**

```
<div class="page-header">
        <h1>Inbox</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @foreach ( $data as $from )
                    {!! $from->from !!} <br>
                <a href="/showmail/{{$from ->id}}">View</a>
                <hr>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```